# How to determine if the user has opened a new Microsoft Word Document?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msdn

A Visual C# form includes a function to create a blank new Microsoft Document when a specific button is pressed.Once the user has clicked on this button ,I need to check if a new Microsoft Document is already created and still activate before creating a new word document,hence one document is opened at a time.

I'm trying to accomplish this using the code below:-

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool  IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

This will return a bool.I do not know how to check the output?Which parameter will I check and what will be the corresponding syntax?The problem that might arise is that the user can open a notepad and this will be the activate window,hence I need to be specific since it only applies to a word documents.Normally,when a new document is create the default name is Document1,but the user has an option of saving and changing the name.

Comment: do you mean new Word document or Word window?

Comment: when the button is clicked, I activate word and create a blank document.We can check either one,I guess.

Comment: But I prefer to check for a new word document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsWindow` is not too useful for what you want (you don't have `hWnd`, the handle of the window). [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be much more helpful; but the problem is that it (and other equivalent WinAPI calls) takes the name of the given window as argument and, for MS Word, this is the name of the document (what I guess that you don't know).

A simple and reliable approach would be looking at the running processes:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] Procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword");
if (Procs.Length >= 1)
{
    //There is an opened Word document
}
```

Comment: Should "winword" be replaced by a specific string?

Comment: @Kribz "winword" is already the specific string. This is the name of the Word processes: this code (reaching inside the condition) predicts reliably whether there is running Word processes (= opened Word docs) or not. Just test it.

Comment: Procs.Lenght value is 2,when I step through the code.This is the case when no word documents are opened or when there is one word document opened.

Comment: @Kribz There are 2 running Word processes for sure. Perhaps some of them don't have an associated window (this can happen when you open Word docs from an application and don't release the given objects properly). By looking at windows (via FindWindow, for example), you might avoid that; but, as said, this cannot be done easily. In any case, having these running processes is indicative that your application is not doing things properly and will be problematic anyway while intending to open a new doc (even though you don't see the window, the given file is opened).

Comment: @Kribz make this experiment to confirm that everything is OK: open the task manager (CTRL+ALT+SUP), kill all the running Word processes (under processes, anything with "winword" on its name) and execute my code: Procs.Length will be zero. Now open a Word document and you will see that Procs.Length is one.

Comment: Sorry,i wish i could say that was the case.No WINWORD.EXE was opened.

Comment: @Kribz the name is not winword.exe; it might contain different bits as "*32". Please, review your processes list and re-confirm that there are word processes (processes INCLUDING winword in its name). I hope that you are not executing my code inside yours (which opens Word documents). Please, review all that and intend to understand what might be happening (or post your exact conditions), but if .GetProcessesByName("winword") says that there are processes called winword it would be a really (but really, really) big surprise to me seeing a situation where not such processes are running.

Comment: It seems that the moment I run my code the WINWORD.EXE appears in task manager,deleting it the lenght was zero but my app crashed.Your code works,the problem lies with the creation of the document as you mentioned above.Is there an alternative

Comment: @Kribz I cannot guess what happens in your code; you should post it (I don't even know how you are connecting to Word). BUT bear in mind that you should only ask one question every time. Your question was how to detect running instances and I have given you quite a few information on this front. If now you realise that this is not the best way through to fix your problem, you should post a different question by explaining exactly what you did, what is the problem, etc. (ideally with code).

Comment: I declare the following gobally:-  // create MS-Word application 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application msWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();                           I think this might be the reason behind the winWord.exe appearing at start up.I will edit my question ,so that you can see what is happening the code.

Comment: @Kribz This is not about YOUR problem. Is about the question you ask which has to be generic enough and worthy to others. I did consider your question to fit in this description and that's why I answered. I can provide you a bit more of help if it is more or less related; but what you are asking now (what I understand that you are asking) is completely different: you need to clarify your ideas regarding Word Interop -> new question with your whole code so far and with detailed explanations of the problems; is the only thing which might  truly help you.

Comment: @Kribz No problem. Please, let me know and, if I am around, will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check Process check running process and get handle id.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process

Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
processName = <Todo: check process_name in the array for word document>
Regex r = WildcardToRegex(processName);

matching = allProcesses.Where((p) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return r.IsMatch(p.MainModule.FileName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }).Select((p) => p.Id);
```

Once you found the process_name and Process ID, you can check if there is a new process(WordDocument in your case) running.